# typed dataset, cascade delete of child table records

Tags: .net, strongly-typed-dataset, relation

I have a typed dataset with two tables like this:

Table A (Parent Table)

```
ID  MessageID   
1     1
2     1
3     2
4      3
```

Table B (Child Table)

```
ID  MessageID   
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

I have a relationship between Table A and Table B on the MessageID column. The delete rule is set to Cascade. I cannot change the design of these tables, it is what it is.

Table A contains two records with MessageID 1. If I delete only one of those, the child record is deleted from Table B, creating an orphan in the second parent table. Is there a way to only delete if there are no other parent records sharing the MessageID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28SQL.80%29.aspx) instead of the cascade-delete, for example(MS SQL-Server, untested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trDeleteTableB] ON [dbo].[TableA]
    FOR DELETE
    AS
    DELETE FROM TableB
    WHERE (MessageID IN
         (SELECT MessageID
           FROM  DELETED
           WHERE (NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT * FROM  TableA
                  WHERE (TableA.MessageID = DELETED.MessageID)))))
```

Another idea is to extend your typed Dataset. If you want to extend the functionality you can't change the generated classes in the DatesetName.designer.cs/vb (it will be recreated on any change) but the file without designer in its name(create it if it not exists). Then you have to extend the partial DataTable-class(look in the designer-file if you don't know the exact name, it's normally f.e. *TableBDataTable*).

Have a look at following code to see what i mean, i haven't tested it but i hope you take my point:

```
Partial Class Datset1
    Partial Class TableBDataTable
        Private Sub TableB_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TableBRowChangeEvent) Handles Me.TableBRowDeleting
            If e.Action = DataRowAction.Delete Then
                '*** check here if there is another TableARow with this MessageID ***'
                e.Row.RejectChanges()
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: I am attempting to do this in the dataset only. I do not intend to update SQL with these changes. (I won't bore you with the reason why)

Comment: The delete rule is also on the database side. Then you have only the option to remove the cascade-delete and check in the application if the child must be deleted or not.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks.

Comment: @Bremer: I've had another idea and edited my answer, have a look.

Comment: I came up with the same solution myself and it works great! Actually, I added my event handler code in a class that’s consuming the dataset. Your placement in a partial class is even better. Thanks!